# How to access the result(s) of a Processing module?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I am experimenting with the QGis Processing toolbox. I open up the module dialogue, set it then parameters and click. If the run succeeds the dialogue is closed automatically and no result(s) are ever shown.

Under the Processing menu there is a dialogue called Results Viewer, but it is always empty.

How can I access the results of a Prossessing module after the dialogue is automatically closed?

Answer (score 3):

The **Results Viewer** is used if the algorithm outputs texts or graphics as described [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/processing/html.html). So if you use multiple algorithms showing, for example, some basic statistics, the results viewer would contain those statistics for each layer.

Also, if you want to keep the dialogue open, you can enable the setting:

`Processing > Options... > General > Keep dialog open after running an algorithm`

---

**EDIT**:

Using QGIS 2.14.1 for Win 7 64-bit, it should be possible to see the results of `r.sum` or `r.statistics`, for example, in the Results Viewer:

[image: Results viewer]

Comment: As I wrote in the question, the Results Viewer dialogue is always empty. As for the module dialogue, if I let it open, it only shows the messages from the GRASS shell, e.g. "Default region was updated to the new projection", but not the result(s) of the module.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa - Which processing modules are you using and what sort of result(s) are you expecting?

Comment: I am trying with simple GRASS modules such as `r.sum` and `r.statisitcs`.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa - Perhaps it's a version and/or platform issue....?

Comment: I am using QGis 2.14.2 on Ubuntu 14.04. The Processing toolbox is presenting GRASS modules that have been deprecated, while missing newer ones, e.g. `r.univar`. This is clearly a bug with either QGis or the Processing toolbox, nothing to do with the platform. Also, the Results Viewer is always empty on this QGis version.

Answer (score 3):

This is being caused by a bug with QGis. I am trying the `r.sum` GRASS module that is listed in the Processing toolbox list. However, this module [was deprecated in GRASS 7](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Grass7/NewFeatures#Replacedandremovedmodules) and replaced by `r.univar`.

Looking closer at the module dialogue, there is actually an error message about it:

[image]

Back to the GRASS shell then.